# Google App Engine 409 Conflict

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine

I've had issues with the Google App Engine 409 conflict when trying to deploy my java application. I've looked at various other questions and had no success as of yet.

This is my appengine-web.xml file. As far as I can tell, there are no modules causing it to give me this error.

I have attempted to rollback the WEB-INF as well as the project itself, but none of it works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>app-id</application>
<version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

If you need any other information let me know. I'm not very familiar with GAE yet, and so I don't know if some of those XML properties could cause it.

I've been looking around and on my console, the app engine version is 1.9.3, but my sdk is 1.9.1. That wouldn't have anything to do with it, would it?

Comment: The `<version>` should be a version of your app - it's a string and you can decide on it's contents.

Comment: That fixed it after I changed the version to match what's online and did a rollback. Thank you very much!